# Stellar Captive Core For Private Network

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

I have set up one stellar private network. Now I want to connect horizon with that private network core in captive mode. So that I have create one stellar-captive-core.cfg file as below

```
[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="bitpaymentz.com"
QUALITY="HIGH"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="Node1"
HOME_DOMAIN="bitpaymentz.com"
PUBLIC_KEY="GD6IY3XE3QVR32WULTVU643F3TDJNHOUQJUJTCMD4TWSCQCXUIZIIUFQ"
HISTORY="curl -sf file:///tmp/Node1/stellar-core/history/vs/"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="Node2"
HOME_DOMAIN="bitpaymentz.com"
PUBLIC_KEY="GADDCNNR7O3VOREM5YGLFB3G7LP6RGTDHVCH7T3KO5Y7WRBOAN2GADFA"
HISTORY="curl -sf file:///tmp/Node2/stellar-core/history/vs/"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="Node3"
HOME_DOMAIN="bitpaymentz.com"
PUBLIC_KEY="GC2V2EFSXN6SQTWVYA5EPJPBWWIMSD2XQNKUOHGEKB535AQE2I6IXV2Z"
HISTORY="curl -sf file:///tmp/Node1/stellar-core/history/vs/"
```

I have ran the captive core  and it is running in 8001 port. After that I ran horizon with ----remote-captive-core-url flag and it is running successfully with 8000 port.
**But during ingestion horizon giving error it's saying, "does match network passphrase, it should be Test SDF Network ; September 2015"**
*But in my stellar-captive-core.cfg file I have mentioned my configuration not stellar configuration.*

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `NETWORK_PASSPHRASE=Test SDF Network ; September 2015` to the environment variable, or via `--network-passphrase=Test SDF Network ; September 2015`